# Help installing fdupes

Tags: apt

I recently downloaded Ubuntu from the microsoft store, and I am looking to install fdupes to get rid of a bunch of duplicate files I have. When i try to install, i'm met with:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fdupes
```

I have looked around but I have no clue how to download the package or any basic Ubuntu options, I am completely new to this. I also only have the terminal window downloaded from the microsoft store. Additionally, if i try to update, i get the error that it cannot reach the archive or security URLs listed.

Please Help

Comment: I don't think WSL is 18.04-capable yet.  `fdupes` is only present in Bionic, so unless you have 18.04 WSL, I don't think you can easily get `fdupes` in the environment without compiling itself.  (Not able to reach the URLs points at a different issue that is outside the scope of the "HOw do I install fdupes" question)

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu from a my Windows 10 PC. 
I had the same problem. This is how i solved:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fdupes
```